# How does one control a Windows PC remotely from Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

I have been trying to remotely access my Windows laptop from my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop without any success. Things that I tried:

1. **RDP** in Windows: My **Windows 10 Home** has no option to activate remote desktop server.
2. I installed **realVNC** on Windows and the **vncserver** showed me the following things:

   - **Connectivity: computerName** belongs to **computerName's Team**, connecting user see this information when they sign in to VNC Viewer.
   - **Security: Identity check:** when prompted, connecting users should check for matching details.
   - Signature: 8 pairs of alphanumerics separated by dashes
   - Catchphrase: A strange sentence
3. Tried to use **Remmina** on Ubuntu - entered the following:

   - Name: ComputerName
   - Group: ComputerName's Team
   - Protocol: VNC - Virtual Network Computing
   - Basic: IP address of the Windows PC
   - User name: Windows user name
   - Password: Windows PC password
   - Color depth: True Color (24 bit)
   - Quality: Poor (fastest)

   Tried to connect... doesn't work.
4. Installed **x11vnc** and tried commands like:

   ```
   x11vnc -display :0 -connect WindowsIP
   ```

   didn't work.

   ```
   x11vnc -display :0 -connect computerName@WindowsIP
   ```

   although no idea where to insert the windows password!

I would really appreciate a clear and step by step list of instructions.

Comment: LogMeIn Pro may suit your needs, but it doesn't officially support Linux and it's expensive.

Answer (score 1):

#### TeamViewer

From the [Features page](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/features/):

> Cross-platform PC to PC, mobile to PC, PC to mobile, and even mobile to mobile connections that support **Windows**, macOS, **Linux**, Chrome OS, iOS, Android, Windows Universal Platform, and BlackBerry.